# How do I mock a URL timeout in Typescript with Jest?

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I'm mocking my payload and mocking fetch for my happy path test, and now I'm having trouble figuring out how to mock the timeout. I want to make sure when the URL timesout, I can see what error message I'm getting and how it's being displayed.

Comment: do you mean browser's native timeout or some library's(axios?) you use?

Comment: When you try to access a URL but it timeouts(I'm assuming that's browser native?).  I'm using node fetch and using jest.mockRejectedValueOnce(though not sure if that's proper). I'd normally use a try/catch in my code in JS, though that's giving me problems in TS

Comment: Post your code, what you have tried and error message